# angular 4 typeahead display only property that has a match in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, bootstrap-typeahead

I have an array of json and two typeahead channels and shows. The value of show depend on the value of channel selected.

```
allChannelShow = [    
{"channel":"tv","showname":["America","Friends","Night"]}, 
{"channel":"radio","showname":["360","pop","News","Special","Prime Time"]}, 
{"channel":"stream","showname":["All In","Reports","Deadline","series","Morning","Live","drama","comedy"]}   
]
```

my .html file

```
<div class="container">       
   <label for="channel">Channel 
     <input formControlName="channel" [typeahead]="allChannelShow" typeaheadOptionField="channel" [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10" [typeaheadMinLength]="0" 
      placeholder="Enter a channel name" required>                                  
   </label>              
</div>
<div class="container">     
  <label>Show                               
    <div *ngIf="channel"> 
      <input formControlName="show" [typeahead]="allChannelShow" typeaheadOptionField="showname" [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10" [typeaheadMinLength]="0" placeholder="Enter a show name" required>
</div>   </label> </div>
```

So if I select :
`radio`, the second typeahead shows will have a select list with these items:
 `["360","pop","News","Special","Prime Time"]`
And I will be able to select a specific a show like `News` or `360` or `pop` not the whole list
if I select :
`tv`, the second typeahead `shows` will have a select list with these items:       `[ {"channel":"tv","showname":["America","Friends","Night]`
 I will be able to select a specific show like `friends` not the whole list

How can I make it happen?

**Update**
Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9zee2g) for what I have now.

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackblitz.com of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @KimKern added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method that returns the show names for a given channel name:

```
getShowNames(channel: string): string[] {
  const channelEntry = this.allChannelShow.find(c => c.channel === channel);
  return channelEntry ? channelEntry.showname : [];
}
```

Assign a template variable to your input so you can retrieve its value

```
<input #channelInput formControlName="channel" [typeahead]="allChannelShow" typeaheadOptionField="channel" [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10" [typeaheadMinLength]="0">
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Set the autocomplete values dynamically with the method and the currently selected channel.

```
<input formControlName="show" [typeahead]="getShowNames(channelInput.value)" typeaheadOptionField="showname" [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10" [typeaheadMinLength]="0" placeholder="Enter a show name" required>
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Try it out in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zygnli?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).